# How do I counter Ayla's Rage ability?

Tags: awesomenauts

I just finished a game of Awesomenauts where I was playing as Voltar. The enemy team had an Ayla who killed me at least 9 or 10 times with her Rage ability.

I don't know what kind of build the enemy player was using, but as soon as they saw me on screen, they'd activate Rage, float up to me, and drain my health dry. The enemy player could move faster than I could so there was no way for me to get away.

I only have around 10 online matches under my belt so I may not have a complete grasp of the game mechanics. (I had to read through the Awesomenauts wiki to even figure out what this infuriating ability/character that kept killing me was *called*.) What am I doing wrong? How can I counter this sort of play?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically: stay away. She'll exhaust herself.

Rage drains Ayla's own life and has a limited range. If you see her flying your way, put some distance between you and make it less desirable (or harder) for her to chase you. Use slow, knockback (for example, healing wave and medbot upgrades for Voltar) and blind (drones) effects to deter her; take cover behind friendly turrets and Awesomenauts.

Unless you're specifically trying to counter an attacking character like that, you should not even be on a direct line of sight from them, or be too far away from something to protect you. Voltar in particular is a very defensive/supportive 'naut who should usually stay behind his teammates (or at least a couple of drones).

Once she stops raging, there's a short cooldown before she can do it again. This is a good opportunity to counterattack if you're playing someone offensive.